# How to use count for a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using the below code to get the count of every case statements which has sum inside the case statements but I'm getting the error message.

```
SELECT
  count(case when SUM(Orders.Sales)>10000 then 1 end) as High,
  count(case when SUM(Orders.Sales)>5000 and SUM(Orders.Sales)<9999 then 
  SUM(Orders.Sales) end) as Medium, 
  count(case when SUM(Orders.Sales)<5000 then SUM(Orders.Sales) end) as Low
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Returns ON Orders.[Order ID] = Returns.[Order ID]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

This is the required output which I'm supposed to be expected.

[image]

Comment: why do you need to count? sums will give a single row

Comment: Your usage of `count` is fine. But you cannot use `sum` like that and the error message clearly spells it out.

Comment: @PM77-1 Not fine.  You can't use two layers of aggregates like this, at least not in SQL Server.

Comment: Please post errors and data as text, not images.

Comment: FYI: `case` is an expression *not* a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel that you should be doing the outer count rollups over a subquery which aggregates by order:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales < 5000  THEN 1 END) AS Low,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales < 9999  THEN 1 END) AS Medium,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN sales >= 9999 THEN 1 END) AS High
FROM
(
    SELECT o.[Order ID], SUM(o.Sales) AS sales
    FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Returns r ON o.[Order ID] = r.[Order ID]
    GROUP BY o.[Order ID]
) t;
```

That being said, I don't actually know what the purpose of joining `Orders` to the `Returns` table is.  If you intend to only find sales amounts from orders which have been returned, then maybe this makes sense.  Otherwise, maybe it doesn't make sense.